# iOS Dev: Map Offset in China

Tags: ios, dictionary, positioning, offset

I made a very simple APP in which I can throw a pin right onto the location I am standing at (just a beginner's practice). But I found a problem.

I swear neither I was moving nor the device thought I was moving. And I directly use the geolocation to set the pin. but the pin and the current-location blue point are hundreds of meters apart.

(By the way, the blue point expressed my real location at the time.)

This is a famous problem of Google Map on iOS in China. Put aside the complicated issue of the so-called national security, where I want help is **what should we do as a developer**. Technically, is there a way, in programming, to figure out what exactly the offset is and correct it?

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

At what time did you place the pin? iOS has up to three sources of location data (cell tower triangulation, Wifi sniffing and GPS) and will keep you up to date with the most accurate. So often you get a not very accurate location, then a more accurate location, then an even more accurate location.

If you have a `MKMapView` open then something you can do is key-value observe on its `userLocation` property rather than starting any sort of `CLLocationManager`. That way you'll always be updated with whatever the map view has decided is the current location, meaning that you don't need to try to match your logic to its.

Comment: I am observing on a MKMapView's userLocation. And I was standing on my dorm balcony, which made me believe the GPS could be quite accurate. Every time I test it, the offset was towards the same direction. So I believe that is not a problem of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on the offset, but haven't gotten a satisfying result yet. The added offset is deterministic, i.e. given a location, the deviated location is fixed. So my goal is to get the deviation function, f(p)=p', where both p and p' are 2D points. You can check [here](http://wuyongzheng.wordpress.com/2010/01/22/china-map-deviation-as-a-regression-problem/) if you are interested.